# Setting up basic authentication Solr 5.3.1 for dummies

Tags: apache, solr, jetty, reverse-proxy, centos7

OK, so I'm not a server guru, but I need to figure out how to set up authentication for our solr server admin page. I'm trying to follow the steps outlined here:

https://lucidworks.com/2015/08/17/securing-solr-basic-auth-permission-rules/

I can't even complete the first step, upload the JSON file. I created the JSON file, but when I go to upload it, I get a "command not found" error when trying to run zkcli.sh. Do I need to set something up with Zookeeper first to get this to run? What should I check?

EDIT: I followed some tutorials online and did the following:

1) set jetty-http.xml to localhost (changing the host to 127.0.0.1) by adding the line:

```
<Set name="Host"><SystemProperty name="jetty.host" default="127.0.0.1"/></Set>
```

2) I also added the following to the apache config file (obv changing to correct path in the path to htpasswd):

```
<Location /solr > 
AuthName "Secure Area" 
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile /path/to/htpasswd/.htpasswd require valid-user 
</Location> 
ProxyPass /solr http://localhost:8983/solr 
ProxyPassReverse /solr http://localhost:8983/solr
```

3) I set up a password via htpasswd. 
4) I restarted the server. I refreshed the solr page and nothing; it's a broken link.

What am I doing wrong?

(Unfortunately every time I do that the solr core also disappears and refuses to load. That's another issue though, which I thought was related to permissions but doesn't seem to be...)

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these steps to get the basic authentication work in solr. 
Assuming you have ubuntu OS and installled the server using the install script.

Step1. sudo vi /opt/solr/server/etc/jetty.xml
    Add the following code towards the end of the file before the "" tag.

```
<Call name="addBean">
    <Arg>
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.HashLoginService">
            <Set name="name">Test Realm</Set>
            <Set name="config"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/etc/realm.properties</Set>
            <Set name="refreshInterval">0</Set>
        </New>
    </Arg>
</Call>
```

Step2. sudo vi /opt/solr/server/etc/webdefault.xml
    Add the following code towards the end of the file before the "" tag.

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Solr authenticated application</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>core1-role</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Test Realm</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

Step3. Create the file "/opt/solr/server/etc/realm.properties" with the following contents:

```
USERNAME: PASSWORD,core1-role
```

The username and password is stored in the following file /opt/solr/server/etc/realm.properties

Comment: Thanks for the response, really appreciate it. We're running solr 5.3.1 on CentOS 7. I found the two files and this all seems much more straightforward, but by 'before the "" tag' do you just mean prior to the closing Configure tag (</Configure>)?

Comment: you can simply append it to the end of the file.

Comment: Hi, so it took me a while to get back to this, but now I have a new related issue. The authentication for the panel worked, but now Omeka (the php application I'm running to use solr) produces this error internally when I'm trying to add or edit files: exception 'Apache_Solr_HttpTransportException' with message ''401' Status: Unauthorized' in [domainname]/httpdocs/omeka/plugins/SolrSearch/lib/solr-php-client/Service.php:364 ." And the line 364 says: throw new Apache_Solr_HttpTransportException($solrResponse);

Comment: FWIW, I spoke to someone more familiar with Omeka and that person said it's not easy to change the app's code to handle the basic auth (at least not easily), but added that "use Apache as a reverse proxy for Solr, set up basic auth for the proxy path, and block access to the Solr port through the firewall" -- do you know how I would do that? I am searching for tutorials online now...

Comment: Another update. I followed some tutorials online and did the following: 1) set jetty-http.xml to localhost (changing the host to 127.0.0.1) by adding the line: <Set name="Host"><SystemProperty name="jetty.host" default="127.0.0.1"/></Set>. 2) I also added the following to the apache config file: <Location /solr >
    AuthName "Secure Area"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile /path/to/htpasswd/.htpasswd
    require valid-user
</Location>
ProxyPass /solr http://localhost:8983/solr
ProxyPassReverse /solr http://localhost:8983/solr
3) I set up a password via htpasswd.

Comment: I restarted the server. Unfortunately the above didn't work at all it seems? When I refresh the solr page it just shows up as a broken link. When I try to use solr search from within the app, it throws solr errors. So the issue seems to be with setting the localhost, I think? What am I doing wrong?